# Adding code to the head section of homepage only

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, head

How do I add code to the head of my homepage only? I did some research and I think it needs to go into layout.xml under  but it doesn't seem to be showing. My code with this added is below:

```
<cms_index_index>
        <update handle="MAP_popup"/>
        <reference name="head">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.MYURL.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.MYURL.com/spanish_store/" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.MYURL.com/portuguese_store/" hreflang="pt-br" />
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="mango_settings/newsletter_popup/enabled"><script>smartwave/jquery/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter_popup">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="mango_settings/newsletter_popup/enabled"><template>newsletter/popup.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

The section I added (and need to add) is:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.MYURL.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.MYURL.com/spanish_store/" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.MYURL.com/portuguese_store/" hreflang="pt-br" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento doesn't give any access at all to the Head section of it and I wanna paste some Snippet code there so that our website's social profiles also appear in the google prview (left section of the reasult's page). If we don't have access to this, we need to install an extension and all the extensions for Magento are very expensive. Please someone reply. That would be [truly Inspiring](http://www.syedusman.com)!

Comment: Your [previous post](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/124351) was very similar and was deleted from the site. Please make sure you review the [help] before attempting to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at doing the following:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="my-block">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link rel="alternative" hreflang="en" href="https://www.MYURL.com/" />]]></text></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Perfect, that seemed to do the trick. Thank you!